# Google spreadsheets: Assign a script to a button with parameters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, parameter-passing

I can successfully assign scripts to images in Google spreadsheets. My problem is with parameter passing.

I have this script to write the current time on a cell.

```
function Time(cell){
  var  d = new Date();
  var timeAsString = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + "/" + d.getSeconds();

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).setValue(timeAsString); 
};
```

I need a bunch of buttons to do this with diferent cells, so I wish to specify which cell the time goes to by parameter.

Many tx.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but this really doesn't solve my problem. I don't want user input. The idea is to have a button associated to each cell. The user just presses a button and the cell is filled with a timestamp. If the user must input the cell name, it's ruined. Current solution works  but it's ugly:

```
function Time(cell){
  var  d = new Date();
  var timeAsString = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).setValue(timeAsString); 
};

function TimeB12(){Time('B12')};
function TimeB13(){Time('B13')};

// about 500 more cells...
```

I then associate script TimeB12 to button next to cell B12, and so on.

Comment: Can you confirm that this is only way to work around this now in 2021?

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can  xD

you must use a prompt , ask the user to input string : `Browser.inputBox`
documentation :  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#inputBox%28String%29

And your script use this string exemple : 'A1'

ex : `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1")`